How to obtain Excel data in the desired form or format?
I was working on the data provided in Excel given in the following pattern.

Now I want to convert the data into the following pattern:

This is just the sample part. I have 50 company names and number of days are 100.
Manually, it would be a tedious job to do. Is there any formula by which I can get the desired result? Kindly help. Thanks for the help in advance.
